# cudatoolkit=11.1 -c conda-forge on Anaconda, but I keep getting an error

Tags: anaconda, cudatoolkit

I'm trying to install `cudatoolkit=11.1 -c conda-forge` on Anaconda, but I keep getting an error

```
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

error message:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_10'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_10
location of failed script: C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Scripts\.cudatoolkit-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
"By downloading and using the CUDA Toolkit conda packages, you accept the terms and conditions of the CUDA End User License Agreement (EULA): https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html"

==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: 'chcp'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.
'chcp'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.
'chcp'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it didn't work, so I tried installing in a different virtual environment. I also searched extensively online, but I couldn't find any solutions for the same error code (`execute(740)`). I'm not sure how to configure it correctly.

cuda version is 11.1
cudnn is already installed